# Generic GIS code repository?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we have a 'Code library'?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/462/could-we-have-a-code-library)

Would it be possible to develop a section of the site to act as a simple code repository? For instance, many articles associated with ArcGIS functions have code "samples", but there are still many that are missing this information. Could we simply use the current SE text formatting to add small code snippets organized by various languages/tools. For example, we could have a C# ArcGIS section that has generic code for simple tasks, such as creating safe geodatabase file names?

I have many generic methods that I reuse often and are not found online that I wouldn't mind sharing if it would save others the trouble of writing it themselves.