# Specific tags/area for code

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Could we have a 'Code library'?](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/462/could-we-have-a-code-library)

I have long been a champion of code sharing, and also of keeping math specific algorithms out of a gis per se.  But is there a searchable area we can have to out up a load of library functions e.g. a point in polygon search, or find perpendicular point on line, etc.  I mean functions specific to GI operations.  I genuinely enjoy the site, and like to encourage sharing in our communtity, but people are 'googling' for code samples first, and maybe it would be a good diea to have a repository here, that people can use?

I think it would be an excellent way to make this a more popular resource on the internet

Comment: I think this is a great question and is well framed.  However, it has already been asked in exactly the same form, and gathered a lot of responses, so let's please continue the conversation in the existing thread.

Comment: Whuber, can you send me a link to that conversation please?

Comment: It has been provided automatically in the "Possible Duplicate" message at the top of your question, Hairy.  You can enter that conversation by providing a reply (which would be great to see) and/or by writing comments to the question and replies already there.

Comment: @whuber - thanks!