# Can we hascode?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred

I really like the [Super Ninja Search Options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search).

What would make search *even better* would be support for `hascode:1`, which would find all posts that contain "code sample" markup.

```
Even though this isn't really code, it would be returned since I formatted it with the curly brackets.
```

Posts containing only bits of code marked up in-line `like this` probably shouldn't be returned.

If SE provided this capability it would be easier to treat gis.SE as a code library, as requested [here](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/462/could-we-have-a-code-library).

Comment: I thought this was going to be a rant about unresearched code questions that are basically "giev me teh c0dez!!!1", but this is even better!

Answer (score 4):

Another thought, code blocks can sometimes be formatted with specific [language tags for syntax highlighting](https://gis.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Would it be possible to search for those? Obviously you can already search for *questions* tagged with a specific language tag but it is not always the case to have a question tagged with the same language that say an answer is formatted with, or with any language.

Something like `hascode:c#` for example, would return questions/answers with code blocks marked with the `<!-- language: c# -->` or `<!-- language: lang-cs -->` markup tags.

Answer (score 0):

This would need to be implemented at the [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com) level and although it was mentioned as an aside in [Improvement of search and search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271613/improvement-of-search-and-search-results) I don't think it has ever been formally requested.

Consequently, I have set it to [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) (to [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com)).