# Can we get Stack Snippets enabled?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, code

Just saw that [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and a few other sites have gotten a new [runnable code snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1) feature.

As far as I can tell it is not enabled for this site -- the toolbar button to access it does not appear:

[image: Stack Snippets button]

I think it would be great to have this enabled on our site as well, since we have so many web development questions.

What say you?

Comment: +1 I'm unlikely to use it personally but am keen to see GIS developers here given full access to all SE available tools.

Comment: A good example is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879439/using-setinterval-with-requestanimationframe/25879656#25879656 'run snippet'

Comment: Lots more examples here as well: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239456/stack-snippets-sandbox-try-it-out-here

Comment: sent an email (to the Stack Exchange Team) requesting it for this site

Comment: This is a brand new feature, but I'm not entirely sure what the plans are for making this available to other sites. But I *did* forward this on to the dev team to be sure they know about your interest. I cannot promise immediate results, but I'll be sure it is on their radar as we learn more about how this feature works with a site in actual practice.

Comment: Robert thanks for the fast and positive feedback we (The GIS SE community) look forward to the dev team potentially implementing this useful tool on GIS SE and other SE sites.

Comment: I think this small addition would improve the forum substantially.

Comment: That is pretty cool. I look forward to that on here too. I wonder what programming languages it is limited to. Is it js and web code only? I know python runs on web servers too, but I'm not sure what that output would look like or what the security issues would be. Can we get the arcpy library? just kidding (but not really).

Comment: @jbchurchill JavaScript, CSS and HTML only, for now. Beyond that, there are obvious licensing issues around arcpy. However, there are a lot of ArcGIS JavaScript API questions that could benefit from this.

Comment: StackOverflow is [proposing changes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/299236/241211) to the editor. I don't know whether they would make it more or less helpful here.

Comment: 5 years later - still no news?

Answer (score 7):

This request came up again in the [site design announcement](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3985/site-design-updates-are-coming) which made us realize we never responded publicly about this. Sorry about that!

I think it wasn't totally obvious from the initial release that snippets are really only for JS/HTML/CSS code (a replacement for jsfiddle.net, basically). A good indicator of whether they'll be useful on a site is the number of answers with javascript in them, and especially posts linking to jsfiddle.

GIS I think is probably borderline for this, though you all are much more familiar with your community than I am. There [aren't many questions referencing jsfiddle](https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=jsfiddle) and the [javascript tag also seems relatively small](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/javascript). I think we're looking at <3% of posts that could benefit from this (vs, say, Stack Overflow where it's more like 10%).

It's pretty easy for us to turn on (just flip a site setting) so the main question is not dev time but whether it's good for the community. Turning it on does [come with some community cost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271647/stack-snippets-being-misused) as users get confused about the new button and occasionally mis-use it leading to weird broken code which needs to be cleaned up.

I'm leaning towards "probably not a good fit for this community", but if you all disagree let me know via a comment here.

Comment: Note that there are a substantial number (~1000) of [questions tagged `arcgis-javascript-api` but *not* `javascript`](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-javascript-api+-javascript) -- not all of these are code questions but I'd guess around half of them are. They just aren't tagged `javascript` for whatever reason. So that probably brings us up to around 5%. Since we're not a programming-only site like StackOverflow, I think it's to be expected that this feature isn't going to be used as much as it is over there, but I think there is enough that it is worth enabling.

Comment: There is a similar trend with other APIs e.g. [`leaflet` (~700)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaflet+-javascript) and [`google-maps-api` (~250)](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api+-javascript). Many of these have answers with links to external demos.

Comment: I do more Py than JS, so I may have some bias, but I imagine the vast majority of users here would be confused by that button and use it for Python. The snippets are cool, but my gut says there will be more edit/corrections to posts than people who'd properly use it.

Comment: Note that it *is* technically possible to run Python in JavaScript via a JavaScript-based Python interpreter such as [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/). The obvious limitations being that it can't do anything outside the browser environment, so no installed packages, reading/writing files, etc. (except perhaps through HTML5 features like LocalStorage). Also highly dependent on the implementation as to what standard Python libraries are supported, if any. The user experience is probably not great since you'd need to have some JavaScript and HTML boilerplate to get it set up, but it is an option.

Comment: For Python http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python it would be popular on GIS-SE. (97 GIS SE pages of results)

Comment: @Mapperz Not sure I understand: do you mean the python-via-javascript package mentioned above? Python won't work with snippets natively anytime in the near future.

Comment: A year later and still no progress on this. StackExchange asked for the community whether this would be helpful but ignored our response. Not having code snippets within gis_stackexchange will just force people to post on stackoverflow instead. Please note that the GIS community is transitioning towards a cloud environment with many of the fastest growing tags benefiting from HTML/JS/CSS code snippets. OpenLayers (2987), Javascript (1720), Leaflet (1423), CartoDB (1016), Google-Maps (990), MapBox (338). It is unlikely that the trend will go back to desktop.