# Site design updates are live!

Tags: discussion, design

A majority of the changes are not visible; these tweaks go along with recent updates that were made to Stack Overflow:

- We have moved the site's CSS to a newly refactored LESS system, so that it's easier for us to fix SE network CSS bugs globally and launch new features in the future.
- We updated some of the graphics to SVG for retina support.
- We've fixed a LOT of obscure bugs that arose when new features were not thoroughly tested across the entire network.
- We are launching the shiny new user profile!

Visually it should "feel" the same as the old site with slight layout adjustments.

This update should retro-actively fix most of the old design bugs. If you see any new bugs, or old ones not yet fixed, please post an answer here to let us know!

Comment: Any chance this will also include the [much-desired](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3771/can-we-get-stack-snippets-enabled) [Stack Snippets](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/?cb=1) feature?

Comment: @blah238 Sorry, that's not part of this update. But I've pinged a few people to try to find out the status of the feature request in the meta post you've linked.

Comment: Will the cosmetic issue described at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/3954 be addressed by this?

Comment: @PolyGeo I posted an answer on the post you linked.

Comment: @blah238 we (moderators) emailed the stack exchange employees (September 2014) regarding snippets from the previous meta question http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3771/can-we-get-stack-snippets-enabled this was not followed up until now. This feature would work very well for GIS SE. maybe kurtis can update on this

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the updates and work! I'm sure it will take a bit to absorb and get used to the changes, and figure out if something is a bug or just new/different.

One thing I noticed, and I'm not sure it's a bug or just a design change, but block quotes used to have a different color background (green) than code blocks/wrap. Now they're the same gray.

> This is a block quote.

```
This is an indented code block.
```

While they do use different fonts and have different properties (scroll bars, auto-formatting, etc.), I found the color distinction to be very helpful/useful.